# How to do a perfect circle with the bezier tool in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, css, animation, path

I need to create a perfect circle with the bezier tool and not with the circle tool. The purpose of this is to later animate my svg with css.

Comment: I wish to note that Bézier curves cannot represent a *perfect* circle (they can do pretty good approximations though).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Why not?

Comment: @Scribblemacher: Bézier curves are polynomial curves and a circle isn’t. It all boils down to the sine function not being a polynome. (A rough analogy is that you cannot represent π as a fraction.)

Comment: @Scribblemacher Trigonometric functions are part of a group called trancendental  functions which can not be described by polynomials. The accuracy is described well  in http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/ anyway you could use rational splines (Beziers or b-splines which are called NURBS) to make accurate circle arcs (altough  they arent paramerized as circles are)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When drawing a citcle in Inkscape then this will be its path [image]:

[image]

To convert this path to Bezier lines just select the object, then choose *Path > Object to Path*:

[image]

We can now insert nodes, break paths or whatever there is we need to do (below example was obtained by inserting 3 nodes and deleting the path between two selected nodes):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Select the  `ellipse tool`, draw a circle (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) and now - with the  `ellipse tool` still selected - hover over the 3 visible nodes of the circle and read the hints in the status line: you can position the start and end point of the circle to create a segment, and with the toggle on the ellipse controls bar you can determine if it's a segment (closed, filled path including the center) or an arc (unclosed shape).

Taken from [This Post](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3469) on the Inkscape forums.